# httpd (WordPress) gets avc denied write (SELinux)

Tags: php, redhat, selinux, deny, rhel7

I'm getting following message in my `/var/log/audit/audit.log`:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1402615093.053:68): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=799 comm="httpd" name="php" dev="xvda1" ino=8667365 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 tclass=dir
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1402615093.053:68): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=no exit=-13 a0=7f7a5ca697a8 a1=241 a2=1b6 a3=1 items=0 ppid=662 pid=799 auid=4294967295 uid=48 gid=48 euid=48 suid=48 fsuid=48 egid=48 sgid=48 fsgid=48 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="httpd" exe="/usr/sbin/httpd" subj=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)
```

pipe `audit2allow` outputs:

```
#============= httpd_t ==============

#!!!! This avc can be allowed using the boolean 'httpd_unified'
allow httpd_t httpd_sys_content_t:dir write;
```

per @Michael I tried, but still having issue wordpress writing to `.htaccess`,`wp-config.php`,`wp-content.`

```
# ls -Z .htaccess wp-config.php 
-rw-rw-rw-. apache apache unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 .htaccess
-rw-rw-rw-. apache apache unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 wp-config.php
# chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t .htaccess wp-config.php 
# ls -Z .htaccess wp-config.php 
-rw-rw-rw-. apache apache unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 .htaccess
-rw-rw-rw-. apache apache unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 wp-config.php
#
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Well obviously that new problem has nothing to do with SELinux. The permissions are just wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1. You can set the type `httpd_sys_rw_content_t` on files you want `httpd` to be able to write to.
2. You can set the `httpd_unified` boolean that was suggested. But this may have other side effects.

Comment: I updated my question as I cannot fit all in comment, basically I tried your suggestions (I think i did it right, please see output) but still having issues `wordpress` to write into `.htaccess` and/or `wp-config.php`(. What side effects were you referring in #2? (since #1 isn't working for me)

Comment: Setting your permissions properly would be a good start, I'd think.

Comment: permissions set according to: http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions

Comment: sorry, i copied and paste wrong from wrong place, so it appeared as read instead of read/write)

Comment: Gawd, there's a lot of bad information in that wiki article. Almost all of it, in fact.